# message error: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 1 at JSON.parse text: "000066/2022"

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I've got an HTTP PUT API and it's working (got a 200 w/response) but I've also got this error in console:

> error: SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at position 1 at
> JSON.parse () at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad  message:
> "Unexpected number in JSON at position 1" stack: "SyntaxError:
> Unexpected number in JSON at position 1\n    at JSON.parse
> ()\n    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad  text: "000066/2022"

service.ts

```
 put(data: any): Observable<any> {
    const url = "/change-status";
    return this.http.put<any>(url, data);
  }
```

component.ts

```
 go() {
    const body = {
      dataTable: this.table, etc.
    };
    const data= {
      id: this.id,
      status: this.status, etc...
    };
    this.service.put(data).subscribe(
      res => {this.service.putData(body).subscribe(
        //   resp => {
        //     this.stepperStoreService.emitId(resp);
        //   });
        this.messageService.add({ severity: 'success', summary: 'Success', detail: 'Your number is

:' + " " + res });
      }
```

PLEASE HELP. DON'T KNOW HOW TO FIX THIS!
Could be the leading zeros?

Answer (score 0):

By default Angular always expects a JSON is response body of the request. Please check the response body of the 200 request and set the response type accordingly. It might be `text/plain`.

`return this.http.put<any>(url, data, { responseType: 'text' });`

Comment: Thanks for help! I've already tried, but in both cases ({ responseType: 'text' } and { responseType: 'text/plain' } returns 204 No content with no reponse,

Comment: @Sophia Perhaps check your API documentation then. You say it returns HTTP 200 one time and then HTTP 204 the other. HTTP 204 usually doesn't have a response body, as the name implies.